# Searching the the lowest Value from a file

Tags: python, list, file

I've included a test sample of my golf.txt file and the code I've used to print the results.

golf.txt:

```
Andrew

53

Dougie

21
```

The code to open this file and print the results (to keep this short I only have two players and two scores

```
golfData = open('golf.txt','r')
whichLine=golfData.readlines()


for i in range(0,len(whichLine),2):
  print('Name:'+whichLine[i])
  print('Score:'+whichLine[i+1])
golfData.close()
```

Can I modify the code I have to pull out the minimum player score with name?  I believe I can without writing to a list or dictionary but have NO clue how.

Help/suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: You need two new variables to keep track of the minimum score and a player. Initialize minimum score to some maximum value. Inside your for loop compare against your minimum score, if less, then store the new minimum score along with the player who scored it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @h0r53 indicated, you can try something like this:

```
golfData = open('golf.txt','r')
whichLine=golfData.readlines()

lowest=float('Inf')
Name=''

for i in range(0,len(whichLine),2):
  if float(whichLine[i+1])<lowest:
    lowest=float(whichLine[i+1])
    Name=whichLine[i]
golfData.close()

print(Name)
print(lowest)
```

Comment: Why not `float('Inf')` for the starting lowest?

Comment: I need to resolve now the inequality between the str of whichLine and float of lowest....i think

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was being dumb and trying to make it a float from the beginning... I also like the use of inf (which is a new thing for me in programming). I was thinking about a way to always have the number we're comparing to as something like n+1 but inf will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min()` function for that:

```
with open('file.txt') as f_in:
    min_player, min_score = min(zip(f_in, f_in), key=lambda k: int(k[1]))

print(min_player, min_score)
```

Prints:

```
Dougie
21
```

Comment: This solution works immediately, but I definatly need to read up on how it works. Being new at this, its great to get it working, unless I don't know/understand what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: @BeardedTorus `f_in` can be iterated - each iteration it returns one line from the file. So `zip(f_in, f_in)` returns tuples in form `(line1, line2), (line3, line4), ...`. `min()` function just find minimum of these tuples based on `key=` function.

Comment: I see, I've yet to work with tuples or the min function.  This does make sense now, it was simply my lack of understanding really of how the min function works.